# Magento 1.14.2.2 Echo order status

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to get the "**Status**" of orders in my **Frontend -> Customer Account Dashboard -> "My Orders"** to display a different wording than the order code of my order status.

Example: In the back-end Admin a new order comes in with a status code "*hold_new*"

I want this status to be displayed as "**New**" in the dashboard.

I have tried to write some PHP but I am fairly new at it and am having some difficulty.

```
<?php 
if ($_order->getStatusCode()){
    $_statusCode == $_order->getStatusCode();
    if ($_statusCode == 'hold_new'){
        echo $this__('New');
    }
    else{
        echo $this__('Not New');
    }
}
?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Below is link to a screenshot of my customer account.

As of now the status column code is :

```
<?php echo $_order->getStatusLabel() ?>
```

I want to the word "New" to show under "Status" NOT "Hold-NEW"

[Customer Account ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0uKa.jpg)

Thanks

Comment: Whats your issue?

Comment: hey i edited my post to try and further explain my issue. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento status can be configured from admin panel. Just navigate to admin panel under `System -> Order Statuses` and edit labels of the statuses you want.

No coding should be needed here.

Cheers.

Comment: thats great thanks but i was trying to do it without changing the actual names and codes of order status.

Comment: This way you don't change the codes, just the label. You can even do it per store view, so the admin labels stay the same.

Comment: That's exactly what i needed. Thanks so much